# I am not able to install vmware on my pc with Kubuntu 17

Tags: vmware, software-uninstall, vmware-player

[image: screenshot for terminal]

When I try to install vmware it shows the license agreement on terminal instead of showing a GUI.

Comment: It may be helpful to tell us your Kubuntu version. Two releases come out each year, so for 2017 there were 17.04 (April release) & 17.10 (October); ie. year.month

Comment: Perhaps you need to accept the license agreement. Try scrolling down.

Answer (score 2):

You can either scroll to the bottom of the agreement and accept it, or alternatively you can  install using the `--eulas-agreed` flag to automatically accept the agreement.